# Sum of count with Splunk

Tags: sum, host, splunk

First let me say that I am very very very new to splunk. I am trying to find all the "host" that make up an index and get a total count of unique values. The purpose of this is to eventually get alerts on when the total "host" changes so I can tell when something that makes up and index stops working.

Here is my query so far which gives me the host names and the count however I cannot figure out how to get the sum of "count"

```
index=exchangesmtp | table host | dedup host | stats count by host | addtotals fieldname=count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

earliest=-30m index=exchangesmtp | dedup host | table host | stats count

This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There's no point in doing a `dedup` before `stats`: `stats` will deduplicate (and is *much* faster: https://antipaucity.com/2018/03/08/more-thoughts-on-stats-vs-dedup-in-splunk/#.XsUeAcYpDNI)

Comment: Also - don't bother running `table` before `stats`: `stats` generates its results into a table

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following is more straightforward

```
earliest=-30m index=exchangesmtp | stats dc(host) as count
```

`stats dc(field)` gives you the distinct count of values in that field, in your case, the number of unique hosts